# Tabpro third party control not converting completely while converted from vb6 to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I migrated an application form vb6 to vb.net. Tabpro third party controls are used in vb6.

The Tabpro control has multiple tabs, when I convert only the first tab of the control was converted. All other tabs are blanked.

Please suggest what the problem Is with the Tabpro table control, is it not compatible with vb.net or is there a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some controls simply cannot be migrated completely to work in VB.Net. Sounds to me as though this just might be one of those controls.